# Rust: Cost of Comparison

Tags: rust

In Rust, is `==` not an `O(1)` operation?

How expensive is it to `==` two large, nearly identical `Vec`s or `BTreeMap`s?

How does Rust perform this operation?

Comment: Both are O(n) for the number of elements.

Comment: To be clear, this isn't Rust-specific per se. The equality operator in _any_ language cannot be done in constant time on arbitrary-sized collections. It's mathematically impossible.

Comment: @JMAA The OP might be coming from Java where `==` is defined as identity comparison, and is therefore always constant-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`==` in Rust is not guaranteed to be O(1). For containers specifically, it may be much costlier.

Both `Vec` (actually slice, since it implements the underlying comparison for both vecs and slices) and `BTreeMap` are O(n) where `n` is the number of elements in the container. Both however are O(1) where the sizes of the compared containers are different.

The code for `BTreeMap` is [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/3c17c84a386e7badf6b2c6018d172496b3a28a04/library/alloc/src/collections/btree/map.rs#L2009-L2013):

```rust
impl<K: PartialEq, V: PartialEq> PartialEq for BTreeMap<K, V> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &BTreeMap<K, V>) -> bool {
        self.len() == other.len() && self.iter().zip(other).all(|(a, b)| a == b)
    }
}
```

The code for slice is [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/3c17c84a386e7badf6b2c6018d172496b3a28a04/library/core/src/slice/cmp.rs#L64-L75):

```rust
impl<A, B> SlicePartialEq<B> for [A]
where
    A: PartialEq<B>,
{
    default fn equal(&self, other: &[B]) -> bool {
        if self.len() != other.len() {
            return false;
        }


        self.iter().zip(other.iter()).all(|(x, y)| x == y)
    }
}
```

Certain types are compared using faster `memcmp()` ([here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/3c17c84a386e7badf6b2c6018d172496b3a28a04/library/core/src/slice/cmp.rs#L78-L94)).

Comment: Make me wonder why the code for slice does not use the same conjunction `equal_len && equal_content`. 5 lines instead of one, and an extra return.

Comment: @Bluehorn Yeah, I wondered about that too. Probably different people, different times, whatever.